# Silverlight: Apply border on a control at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight

I am having a StackPanel on left hand side of page, in which I am adding Comboboxes at runtime, on selection of item of any combobox I am showing relevant information on right hand side. I want something like that if any combobox get active a border should be applied on that combobox, I can't use onfocus because as soon as I click on  the relevant information at right hand side the border goes away.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you think of using a [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox(v=vs.95).aspx) instead of a StackPanel? It highlights the selected item for you. It uses a colored background instead of a border, but of course you can set the [ItemContainerStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.itemcontainerstyle(v=vs.95).aspx) using a modified copy of the ListBoxItem style available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278062(v=vs.95).aspx).

Comment: Andrew has the right idea. Instead of a stack panel (which is probably being populated in code-behind) use a ListBox with a ItemTemplate DataTemplate set to a combo box and either customize the list box's highlight, to suit, or replace it with a border. Bind the list box to an ObservableCollection of whatever objects the combo box should be deriving it's binding from. Beyond that, you'll need to be more specific about what's driving the list and the combo boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's psuedo-code of one solution:

```
void AnyComboBoxSelectionChanged(ComboBox selectedBox)
    foreach combobox in stackPanel
        combobox.border = none
    selectedBox.border = highlightedBorder
```

That is, use the `SelectionChanged` events of the comboboxes to set the borders as needed.